# Dax - How calculate discount

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to calculate a discount between a period with DAX, but it is not working.

I have a table with a discount period '2020-01-01' to '2020-03-01', but when calculated, all rows show a discount in all months. I want to calculate only interval. I also tried with DATESBETWEEN but in success. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
DiscountDax =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Desconto[Discount] );
    FILTER (
        Faturas;
        Faturas[SaleDate] >= MIN ( Desconto[StartDate].[Date] ) && 
        Faturas[SaleDate] <= MIN ( Desconto[EndDate].[Date] )
    );
    ALL ( Faturas )
)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Move discounts into Faturas table and eliminate Desconto table. Then your DAX will be simple.

Comment: @RADO Tks worked perfectly